# Continuity of conjugate of $z$: $f(z)=\bar z$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove that the function $\;f(z)=\bar z\;$
is continuous on the whole plane?

Comment: Sorry...I'm trying to put a short bar above z...

Comment: Cool.. Thanks...

Comment: Now that the notation is settled, can you tell where you're stuck and what you have attempted?

Comment: I tried the Cauchy Riemann Equation... Which tell me it's not analytic everywhere .. And by definition of limit .. I cannot get it be zero as the small change goes to0

Comment: @leave2014 use Weierstrass $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity at $z_0$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** $$ |z - z_0| = |\bar{z} - \bar{z_0}|. $$

Then use [Weierstrass $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_definition_.28epsilon-delta.29_of_continuous_functions) of continuity at $z_0$.

> We want to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that if $|z-z_0|<\delta$, then $|f(z)-f(z_0)| = |\bar{z}-\bar{z_0}| = |z-z_0| < \epsilon$. We can take $\delta$ equal to $\epsilon$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

As a function from $R^2$ to $R^2$, $f(x,y)=(x,-y)$.
Both components are polynomial, so they are continuous, hence $f$ is.